# How to connect to Oracle-DB ODBC connection string using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, odbc

I am trying to connect to oracle-db using the odbc connection string, I am able to make the connection using pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
connection_string = 'DRIVER={Oracle};DBQ=X.X.X.X/YY/dbname;UID=someuser;PWD=XXXXXX'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

but I am not able to connect using SQLAlchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)
db_engine = create_engine(f"cx-Oracle+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy is giving the error

Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'cx-Oracle+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#dialect-oracle-cx_oracle-connect), the URL should begin with `oracle+cx_oracle://`. SQLAlchemy does not support ODBC connections for Oracle.